# Ionic => Runtime error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: ionic-framework

Error:
[image]

I am facing a problem when I run the code via `ionic serve`
 I get an error of 
**Runtime error: Cannot find module "."**

App.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { SigninPage } from '../pages/auth/signin/signin';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages/auth/signup/signup';
import { LandingPage } from '../pages/landing/landing';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    SigninPage,
    SignupPage,
    LandingPage
  ],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AuthService,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

I haven't mention the entrycomponents
and all the components contains the default code. AuthService is also empty

If I remove the AuthService form Providers in app.module file Code runs succesfully. But if I have to access the authService I must provide it in the Providers

Comment: This happens if something is not imported correctly. For example NavController has to be imported from ionic-angular, not ionic-angular/umd - that does vs code automatically.

Comment: the problem is only in the app.module.ts file or in other file @ Gregor Ojstersek

Comment: Can you share the code in app.module file? And maybe one other random component?

Comment: @Gregor Ojstersek Post edited

Comment: Check the imports in all your ts files including AuthService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IonicPageModule is missing from your project.

In your `app.module.ts` include

`import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';`

And your import should looks like this:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
```

after that run `npm run-script build`

NOTE: IonicPageModule is an NgModule that bootstraps a child IonicPage in order to set up routing.

Comment: Happy coding :)